# Dynamic Changing of Android Language

Tags: android

I have an android application working as UI for the device. I mean, when I open the device I don't see the default android interface, instead of it  I see my application. When I change the Android language, the os strings of android change but my applications strings don't. It needs to be restarted. After the restart it changes, but this is not what I want. Because, that application is my main app, and I have to restart the all system to restart the application. 
As you will understand, this application works for all system lifetime. So I need that, change its language while it's running, without restart.

How can I do that?

Note that: Locale is not working for the thing what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Call the following in your **onCreate** method to pick the language provided as in locale string.

```
/**
 * Set the default Locale for app
 * @param context context on which the locale will be implemented
 * @param locale new locale for example, <b>sv</b> for Swedish or <b>en</b> for English
 */
public static void setDefaultLocale(Context context, String locale) {
    Locale locJa = new Locale(locale.trim());
    Locale.setDefault(locJa);

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locJa;

    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    locJa = null;
    config = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, are you sure that it is working? Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Ok I'll try again. My structure is a little bit different, there are no onCreate or setContentView methods, so I think I can't find the right place to call this function.

Answer (score 1):

you can change language by using this function..

```
  public void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;


    String languageToLoad  =lang; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    DebugLog.d("Selectedlang"+lang);


}
```